# Highlight all references to X?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide

The Eclipse IDE has a neat little feature that I really miss in Visual Studio.

If I place the cursor on a variable or method name, the IDE will automatically highlight all references to it in the current document within the relevant scope.

I can't seem to find an option to turn on similar behaviour in VS2008 or Resharper 4.  I know VS has a Find Usages function, but I'd like to do it automatically on the fly.

Does anyone know of a free addin which will add this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using ReSharper, you can highlight the usages in the file with Shift-Alt-F11. Place your cursor on the variable you want to find usages of, and press the Shift-Alt-F11 combination.

Answer (score 2):

There is an add-in for Visual Studio that will do something similar called [RockScroll](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingRockScroll.aspx). 
When you double click on something, it will highlight all occurrences of the item you double clicked. It also changes the vertical scrollbar to a "syntax highlighted thumbnail view" showing an overview of where the item occurs in the file.

Comment: Note that RockScroll doesn't highlight by entity, but by string. But it is an excellent plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I know you mentioned ReSharper, but CodeRush has a nice references window that you can dock and let it search for things on-the-fly or on demand.  As a bonus, you can select each usage and it will show you the context surrounding the usage.  It also works for methods.

I mentioned CodeRush since they have an [express edition](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/), which looks like it includes that feature, but I haven't tried that edition.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 has sorta implemented this, but the feature is somewhat lacking. There is a non-configurable delay between placing the cursor and highlighting.

The RockScroll Addin is not available for Visual Studio 2010 and above.

As a replacement, the free ["Highlight all occurrences of selected word"](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b92b6ad-f563-4705-8f7b-7f85ba3cc6bb) plugin will highlight all occurences of the selected string after a doubleclick. There is no delay as with the native vs2010 highlighter.

It is string-based, which means it works inside comments and string literals.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft published a tool that sort of does what you want. 
Some of my favourite features:

- Enhanced Scrollbar
- Auto Brace Completion
- Ctrl + Click Go To Definition
- Open Containing Folder
  and the list goes on.

For [Visual Studio 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) and for [Visual Studio 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd)